# Correct way to setup Flow with draft-js

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, draftjs

I am trying to use [Flow](https://flowtype.org) with [draft-js](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/).

**package.json dependencies**

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "draft-js": "^0.9.1",
  "immutable": "^3.8.1",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "flow-bin": "^0.37.4"
}
```

I installed the type definitions with [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) by running `flow-typed install`.

Here's some slightly modified code I copied from draft-js docs which I am trying to validate with flow.

**index.js**

```js
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  state: {
    editorState: EditorState
  }

  onChange: Function;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});

    // gives type error, as expcted
    let a :string = 10;

    const editorState :EditorState = this.state.editorState;

    // should be a type error, editor.getCurrentContent() returns type ContentState
    const content :string = editorState.getCurrentContent(); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**.flowconfig**

```
[ignore]
.*\/node_modules\/draft-js\/lib\/.*.js.flow.*

[include]

[libs]
.*\/node_modules\/draft-js\/lib\/.*.js.flow.*

[options]
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
suppress_type=$FlowIssue
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIssue
```

However, when I run `flow` command, I don't get any errors when I call draft-js API. What is the correct way to setup flow here for use with draft?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ignored files in your `.flowconfig`, then `[libs]` will also ignore them, so you'll need to remove `.*\/node_modules\/draft-js\/lib\/.*.js.flow.*` from `[ignore]`.

In order to get flow & draft-js working together I also needed to set the `suppress_comment` to the same value used in draft-js:

```
[options]
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe\\($\\|[^(]\\|(\\(>=0\\.\\(2[0-8]\\|1[0-9]\\|[0-9]\\).[0-9]\\)? *\\).*\n
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Flow doesn't work with draft-js when import it as `'draft-js'` is that:

- draft-js' main file is `lib/Draft.js`. This means that `import {Editor} from 'draft-js'` equals to `import {Editor} from 'draft-js/lib/Draft.js'`.
- From Flow version 0.19.0, it treats files that end with `.flow` (read [this blog post](https://flow.org/blog/2015/12/01/Version-0.19.0/)) and draft-js 0.9.1 has `lib/Draft.js.flow`.

  - But **it does not have `@flow` declaration**.
- (And you are ignoring draft-js in `.flowconfig`)

so you can solve this problem briefly by adding `@flow` to `node_modules/draft-js/lib/Draft.js.flow`. Or import `Editor` and `EditorState` from `draft-js/lib/DraftEditor.react` and `draft-js/lib/EditorState` respectively.